# Changing array values through drop down selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am trying to manipulate a grid of scores using a drop down menu. Every time I add a new battle result the previous result is deleted from the grid. I am not sure if this is due to how I am looping through and displaying the grid or because of how the array is being stored on this server.

This is how I am storing the data on the server:

```
app.post("/postScores", function(req , res){ 
   res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

  var results = [
    [req.body.e, "x", req.body.f, req.body.g],
    [req.body.h, req.body.i, "x", req.body.j],
    [req.body.k, req.body.l, req.body.m, "x" ]
    ];
  res.json(results);

  res.end();

});
```

And here is how I am trying to manipulate it on the client side:

https://jsfiddle.net/Amidi/egp1hst3/9/

Answer (score 0):

it's a grid or an array of scores? if you delete the previus result it's just an array. if thats the problem use "push" to add a new record to your grid.

```
var arrayScores = [];

$(function(){
$("#btnAddResults").click(_doAddResult);
});

function _doAddResult()
{
var result = [
$("#drop1").val(),
$("#drop2").val(),
$("#drop3").val()
];

arrayScores.push(result);
}
```

If you want to use OOP add elements not arrays

```
var result = {
drop1: $("#drop1").val(),
drop2: $("#drop2").val(),
drop3: $("#drop3").val()
};
```